# Is there an existing library for describing arbitrary binary payloads?

Tags: parsing, binary-data

I have a few protocols that I am trying to parse for a personal project. I realize that I could create custom code using Python's `struct` library or the like, but I was wondering if there was an existing library that could describe how to parse a binary payload in a more declarative manner. If I could make wishes come true the library would take some input looking like the following and generate a parser for me:

```
{
    messageType: exampleMessage,
    messageAttributes: {
        endianness: little, 
        pack: ALIGNED},
    dataStructure: [
        {name: messageId, type: int16},
        {name: payloadSize: type: int32},
        {name: payload: type: utf_8, size: {ref: payloadSize}},
        {name: checksum: type: CRC32, context: example_message}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [MessagePack](https://msgpack.org/), it's like JSON but fast and small? It is an efficient binary serialization format. It lets you exchange data among multiple languages like JSON. But it's faster and smaller.

Comment: this is a nice library, but I was not looking for an existing serialization format but instead a declarative framework for describing arbitrary binary formats. Since asking the question, I think the best solution is a parser-combinator library. It isn't entirely declarative, but it gets the job I want done of parsing and marshalling messages without me doing a bunch of bit fiddling.